# Python Selenium find element (title) in a specific date

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium to get back some articles issued on a specific date

I tried:

```
driver.get('https://www.globalcapital.com/Asia/Bonds/Corp')
while True:
    links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@title,'01 Feb 2021')/preceding::a[2]")]
    for link in links:
        # I want to return all href first to a csv
        # and then return to the title of the article
```

But 'not a valid XPath expression', I have two questions here:

1. is proceeding only used for siblings element?
   2.how could I get date and go back to element to exact the href and get text?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not valid because you forgot closing square-bracket. Try

```
"//div[contains(@title,'01 Feb 2021')]/preceding::a[2]"
```

And no, `preceding`/`following` axes not used for siblings only. `preceding-sibling`/`following-sibling` used for siblings only

Comment: Thank you so much JaSON, but it returns nothing, is it because the website is not allowed scrapping

Comment: @Cathy I guess you should replace `[contains(@title,'01 Feb 2021')]` with `[contains(text(), '01 Feb 2021')]` to make it work

Comment: yes, it worked! so could I always use text() instead of title? as it title works, text()should also work?

Comment: @Cathy no. You should use exact predicate. Text won't be always the same as @title. If element has text - use `[text()="<SOME TEXT>"]` predicate, if it has `title` attribute - use `[@title="<SOME TITLE>"]` predicate. I just don't see div with `title="01 Feb 2021"` on shared page so I suggested to use `text()`...

Comment: I got it, thank you so much for the elaborate explanation, but sorry for another question as I use'links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'01 Feb 2021')]/preceding::a[2]")]
for link in links:
   title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="ssa-default-article__link"]').text', it gives me not the text in the date, but the first two in the page,

Comment: @Cathy try `data = [{link.text: link.get_attribute('href')} for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'01 Feb 2021')]/preceding-sibling::h3/a")]`

Comment: Actually I want  the tile and href to be sperate columns as I want to put them into two column into a csv file, it that possible

Comment: @Cathy , you can iterate over resulting list and put *keys* to one CSV column and *values* to another.. or lust do `titles = [link.text for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'01 Feb 2021')]/preceding-sibling::h3/a")]    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'01 Feb 2021')]/preceding-sibling::h3/a")]`

Comment: I have tried the second one, and when write titles to csv 'Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (1, 3)', should I use two for loops? `for link in links: for title in titles`

Comment: think two for loops work! but no idea why the results return two times,

Comment: @Cathy I'm not sure I got your problem, but try `for link, title in zip(links, titles):`

Comment: the results like tile: a and b, they return two times to csv, like I got: aabb and hrefs for them each

Comment: @Cathy , sorry, I have not much experience in extracting data to CSV. You'd better to submit new question with this issue